# 'tokenupdateverifysig' on etherscan.io will not seem to process without error for me, please help

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, etherscan

Playing around with creating an erc20 as we all do, this is the bare minimum of a coin, I'm being a script kiddie douche in that sense so preemptive apology.

I've made it this far and plan to go public by the end of the week but can't seem to get through:

https://etherscan.io/tokenupdateverifysig

**If you haven't been there it asks for: Contract Owner/Creator Address:**

I've been using the address with all the tokens in it and metamask to sign it, they're the same address.

**Message Signature Hash:**

I've copied the string out of the signed message with no quotation marks

**Enter the original message that was signed:**

I've been copying the whole thing every time and inserting it (being the brackets)

**Troubleshooting:**

This should be field 1: 0xa1d06be35a7c510db96df8ab238ca179eb66446c

**Error:**

It has been saying to ' Please enter valid Token Contract Address in the signed message.'

as far as I know I have been, I'm using the address: 0x2799d90c6d44cb9aa5fbc377177f16c33e056b82

This is the 'to' value / contract address.

**Possible solution:**

Am I messing up on the formatting of the message? It provides this template:

[Etherscan.io dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss] I, hereby verify that the information provided is accurate and I am the owner/creator of the token contract address [token contract address].

Does it want the current date and time? What should be in the first brackets entirely?

Do I keep the brackets for the contract address? It just seems super fragile.

Thanks so much for taking the time for reading this!

Comment: having the exact same issue as you, subscribed in the hope somebody can help

Comment: Hey man, OP here;

When you go to do this process;put your contract address in the brackets, now copy that pre-filled message into MEW and sign that,

Provide the owner address, and then the signature, but only have the message in the last box